# Segmentation Fault 11, Looking for a flag as input - C

Tags: c, infinite-loop

Hello I'm working on a version of Mastermind and I'm almost done. I tried implementing a "debug mode" where it would show the answer if a flag is entered as input. My implementation has gone very wrong as it's stuck in an infinite loop. The problem is in the function getGuess. any suggestions on a fix or alternate solution will be greatly appreciated

I updated the code with suggestions from you great people. but now upon executing I run into a segmentation error 11.

```
#include<stdio.h>
 #include<math.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>
 #include<time.h>
 #define CODELENGTH 4
 #define NUMSYMBOLS 6




void genCode (int MasterCode[])
{
int i=0;
int k;
while (i < CODELENGTH){

MasterCode[i] =rand() %NUMSYMBOLS +1;
    i++;

}//end while loop.
for ( k = 0 ; k < 4; k++ ) {
    printf( "%d ", MasterCode[ k ] );
}

printf( "\n" );
}


void printMasterCode(int MasterCode[]){
int k;
for ( k = 0 ; k < 4; k++ ) {
    printf( "%d ", MasterCode[ k ] );
    printf("\n");
}
}



void getGuess (int guess[], int argc, char **argv, int MasterCode[])
{

int number = 0;
int j;
int k;
printf( "Please enter your list of 4 numbers between 1 and 6: " );


    if (strcmp(argv[1], "-b") == 0) {
        printf("Flag -b passed\n");
        printMasterCode(MasterCode);

    }


for ( j = 0 ; j < 4; j++ ) {
    scanf( "%d", &number );
    guess[ j ] = number;
}

printf( "The guess of " );

for ( k = 0 ; k < 4; k++ ) {
    printf( "%d ", guess[ k ] );
}

printf( "\n" );
}


int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
srand ( time(NULL) );
int MasterCode[4];
int guess[ 4 ];
int exactMatch;
int closeMatch=0;
int exactResult;
int closeResult = 0;

genCode(MasterCode);
do {
    getGuess(guess, argc, argv, MasterCode);
    exactResult = checkExactMatches(MasterCode, guess, exactMatch);
    closeResult = checkCloseMatches(MasterCode, guess, closeMatch);
    printf("%d = Ending exactMatches \n", exactResult);
    printf("%d  = Ending closeMatches \n", closeResult);

} while (exactResult != CODELENGTH);






}
int checkExactMatches (int MasterCode[], int guess[], int exactMatch )
{
int woot;
for(woot=0; woot<4; woot++){


        if (MasterCode[woot] == guess[woot]){
            printf("Exact Match found \n");
            exactMatch ++;
            printf( "%d = Guess \n" , guess[ woot ]);
            printf( "%d = MasterCode \n", MasterCode[ woot ]);
            printf("%d = exactMatch \n", exactMatch);

        }// end if

        if (MasterCode[woot] != guess[woot])
            printf("No EXACT match \n");


}//end for loop

return exactMatch;
} // end checkExactMatches



int checkCloseMatches (int MasterCode[], int guess[], int closeMatch )
{
int k;
int j;
for(k=0; k<4; k++){

    for (j=0; j<4; j++) {


        if (MasterCode[j] == guess[k]){
    printf("CLOSE Match found \n");
    closeMatch ++;
    printf( "%d = Guess \n" , guess[ j ]);
    printf( "%d = MasterCode \n \n", MasterCode[ k ]);
    printf("%d = closeMatch \n \n", closeMatch);

}// end if

if (MasterCode[j] != guess[k])
    printf("No CLOSE match \n");


    }//end nested for loop
}//end for loop

return closeMatch;
} // end checkCloseMatches
```

Comment: I don't see an infinite loop in getGuess, but I do notice you're taking 5 inputs instead of 4.

Comment: When this code is compiled and ran itll ask for the input. You may enter your guess without a flag but it won't start. If your input is just the flag -b it will start but never end

Comment: And I changed the number of inputs thinking it would help recognize if there was a flag entered at the end of your guess. But I don't want it to make the program that way anymore. I want it to either read the flag and display the answer or just read the guess and execute the program.

Comment: You should use `CODELENGTH` instead of the literal `4` when you initialize `MasterCode`

Comment: If this is the current (edited) code, then you're still not checking argc. You need to make sure `argc >= 2` before touching `argv[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not infinite loop in the traditional sense. Your program is expecting a fifth number to be entered.
Also the parameter "-b" should be in argv[1].
argv[0] would contain the program name.

The seg fault is now due to argv[1] being NULL, when there are no command line arguments.
so one should check

```
if (argc>1 && strcmp(argv[1],"-b")==0)
```

Comment: +1, but on a side note, `argv[0]` doesn't always store the path to the executable, what is there is implementation defined.  From the standard: *[5.1.2.2.1] the array members argv[0] through argv[argc-1] inclusive shall contain pointers to strings, which are given implementation-deﬁned values by the host environment prior to program startup.*

Comment: I changed the parameters so It's only expecting 4 numbers and I also changed the argv to 1 I get a segmentation fault 11

Answer (score 1):

You #define CODELENGTH but then use magic numbers (4 in some places and 5 in others) through out the code. Use the #defined value and you'll no longer have an infinite loop (you need to input 5 numbers for it to work).

As others have said: argv[0] contains the name of the program as it was run (or even more detail from Ed S. - maybe it doesn't). The argument you want to look at is argv[1]. But make sure to test argc first as argv[1] isn't guaranteed to exist! (neither is argv[0] if argc is 0).

Comment: I attempted those suggestions and the program would exit on a segmentation fault 11

Comment: Where does it seg fault - put in some trace statements? Start a new question if you have a new question. The above code isn't reading argc before accessing argv[1] - this can cause a seg fault. And you still have multiple magic numbers floating around the code rather than CODELENGTH.